# What do I do if my spawn point is in lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was roaming around and died. My spawn point changed because the last bed I slept in got destroyed, and my original spawn point is covered in lava. Now what do I do?

Comment: I wonder how you got the whole spawn area to be covered in lava...

Comment: I'd guess, catch on fire?

Comment: If original spawn is in lava, how did you escape it in the first place?

Comment: Why does it matter how it happened? (He put it there / uncovered a lava lake / Herobrine did it)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs: Irony? ;)

Comment: Then he should have put it at his spawn point...

Comment: ok i didnt remember where my original spawn point was and never thought about it after my spawn point was put in my base so went off exploring and made a bed so i could skip to morning while exploring and didnt know that my spawn point would change when the bed was destroyed so awhile ago put lava on a mountain cause i thought it would be pretty cool

Answer (score 16):

**Option 1:**

As soon as you spawn, look straight down and break the block below you. (yes, while on fire)

This will change your spawn point to a few blocks away. If you spawn in the lava again, repeat. Do this enough times and hopefully you'll spawn in a safe place.

Please note, that on SMP, you will automatically spawn at a random location in a spawn area.

---

**Option 2:**

You can also edit your save world in SMP. Download the [Minecraft Server](https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/Minecraft_Server.exe) and place it in a folder on your desktop. Open it, let it generate a world, then close it. You've just created your own personal Minecraft server.

Now go grab your single-player world files from the `saves` directory of [your Minecraft folder](http://windows7themes.net/minecraft-save-file-location-windows-7.html) and replace the world generated by your server (the files you'll be copying are the ones labelled `data`, `DIM-1`, `level.dat`, etc). **Make a backup** of these files as well, in case something goes wrong. Next, open the server_properties file of your new server (using a text editor like Notepad or Wordpad) and change `gamemode` from 0 to 1. You are now invincible, allowing you to make whatever changes you want to your world (like cleaning up your lava spill) without dying. To access your world via SMP, open Minecraft, select Multiplayer and then choose Direct Connect to `127.0.0.1`.

When you're satisfied with your changes, close the server and change `gamemode` back to `0`. Open and close the server one final time to save this change (lest your world be stuck in Creative mode). Copy the world files back into [your Minecraft folder](http://windows7themes.net/minecraft-save-file-location-windows-7.html). The changes you made through your SMP server will have saved, and your spawn area will be safe again.

Comment: ive tried and tried over and over again i just keep falling down and im getting into the cobblestone and cant hit through it fast enough

Comment: @TomWijsman I just tested it, and it worked in both 1-player and SMP. Destroying the block that I spawn on top of will change the spawn point by about 4 blocks diagonally (spawning me at a different X-Z co-ordinate entirely).

Comment: Based on this not working for Anthony I would speculate your spawn point only changes if your spawn block _is air_ (not if it is destroyed). Since Anthony's spawn point is in lava, lava will flow into the hole and his spawn point block is now lava, which is not air and so the spawn point is not changed. (I deleted + reposted this comment, I should stop doing that)

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Tricky situation. I'll add a workaround for general world fixes, bypassing the spawn issue altogether.

Comment: @Keaanu: Not true, look it up on the Wiki, on SMP you spawn in a spawn area and not on a single block.

Comment: @TomWijsman Interesting. It seems as though the spawn change is automatic in SMP, instead of triggered like in single player. But that only means that if Anthony was playing SMP, there wouldn't be an issue, as he'd eventually spawn in a safer place.

Comment: @Keaanu: I didn't know that in Single player the player spawns on the exact same spot until the block breaks. I'm used to the SMP where they have a large spawn area that prevents a player from messing with the spawn, you can't change the blocks unless you are an admin; unless you bring creepers or place a TNT right outside the area. It takes a lot of time to mess the whole spawn up...

Comment: @keaanu It sounds like he covered his entire spawn area in lava, judging by the comments on the question, so he won't eventually spawn outside of the lava.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If that's the case, then there's no way he can spawn without dying a few seconds later. Thus, option 2 should be taken to clean up the spawn in creative mode.

Answer (score 5):

It seems from your response to Keaanu's answer that 'legitimate' means aren't working for you. If you resort to slightly less conventional means, then it's up to you how you solve the problem, here are a few suggestions:

- Enable creative mode for you map, place a bed on the edge of the lava pool where you can get to it before dying. Respawn until it's night, sleep in the bed. This will reset your spawn point.
- Hack in a bucket of water to your inventory using TooManyItems immediately upon spawning, and place it straight away. It will solidify the lava.
- Hack in solid blocks and place as many as you can while you're alive to fill up the lava pool.
- Use a map editor such as MCEdit to move your spawn point, or just remove the lava.
- Install Single Player Commands and use `/platform` to place a glass block where you are, `/health` to give yourself enough health to escape, make a bed and reset spawn, or `/jump` if you can see some water. `/tele x y z` would work too.

Comment: If using SPC, `/damage` (toggles *all* player damage) is probably more effective than `/health`.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to try to run in each direction to get out of the lava.
If that doesn't work, you need a map editor to move your spawn point slightly...

Another solution is to find a way to make yourself invulnerable, or try to enable creative mode.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do any of those because the lava is on half the mountain and the spawn point is in the middle of the lava

Comment: @AnthonyHillery: Trying to run and jump in every possible direction (N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW) might be able to get you out of the lava...

Comment: @TomWijsman I assume that, without armor, he would still burn to death.

Comment: @Keaanu: I don't know for sure how the lava system works, but the fire might stop before he burns to death or he might be able to jump in water.

Comment: i have no armour or anything and the lava is like the whole half side of a mountain so probably like 50 sqs wide and im like 10sqs from the side while the water is like 100sqs away

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably really late for this, but by leaving and re-joining the game, you get around 3 seconds of spawn invincibility. Repeat this until you've made it out of the lava.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the Game Menu, and click the button that says open to lan, after that you can change cheats to on, and go to creative mode.